# Checking if ViewController is already in background or not

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app which starts with different VCs depending whether the user is already logged in or not.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController: UIViewController

    if DataManager.getInstance().getUserInfo() == nil {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("authenticationViewController")
    } else {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("locationsNavigationViewController")
    }

    window!.rootViewController = initialViewController;
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible();

    return true
}
```

If the user is not logged in, the app starts with `AuthenticationViewController`, otherwise it starts with `LocationsNavigationViewController`, which is a `NavigationViewController`

In the latter VC, the is a button for logout. The problem is when the user taps on that button, I don't know if I have to dismiss the `LocationsNavigationViewController` (because `AuthenticationViewController` is in background) or if I have to dismiss `LocationsNavigationViewController` and perform a segue for opening the `AuthenticationViewController`.

So far, I have just covered the first use case. So in `LocationsNavigationViewController` I call this function

```
func showAuthentication() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

But when the app starts with `LocationsNavigationViewController` dismiss the VC is not enough of course, because the the `AuthenticationViewController` has never been instantiated.

How can I solve this please?

Comment: Are you using `UINavigationController` as a `rootViewController`?

Comment: you aren't presenting anything, you're setting as the window root view controller, so you don't dismiss anything

Comment: if you want both the rootviewcontroller than add some good animation for changing rootviewcontroller you can remove old rootviewcontroller and add new rootviewcontroller. otherwise add one bool value in your location controller like isUserLogin or not and load appropriate view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers
```

This is an array which will contain all your previous view controller. You can enumerate it and check whether your view controller is exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UINavigationController` then you can check any `UIViewController` present or not!

```
let rootViewController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

if !rootViewController.viewControllers.contains(UIViewController_Class()){

    let notificationVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(constInstance.notificationsIdentifier) as! UIViewController_Class_Name
    rootViewController.pushViewController(notificationVC, animated: false)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The AuthenticationViewController is not inside the UINavigationController, it's just a standalone View Controller

Comment: For better approach you need to put `UINavigationController` as `rootViewController`. @DanieleVitali

Comment: I used part of your code and made it works. I will post the solution soon. Thanks

Comment: @DanieleVitali Great!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sohil's answer, I change the `showAuthentication` function in this way

```
func showAuthentication() {
    //Since the app can start with different VC, I have to check which is the window root VC
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].rootViewController is AuthenticationViewController {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("authenticationSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

And added a segue from the `NavigationViewController` to the `AuthenticationViewController`, called `authenticationSegue`

Pretty simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one function in appdelegate for logout 
and in logout function chanege rootviewcontroller of window like

```
 func logoutUser()
    {

            var login: UIViewController?
            login = LoginViewController(nibName : "LoginViewController", bundle : nil)
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: login!)
            self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    }
```